# reverse classification with mapclassify pysal library?

Tags: python, classification, gis, pysal

quick theoretical/coding question.

I am trying to create an index that reverse classifies median household income, assuming that in a vulnerability index, lower income census tracts are more vulnerable.

Presently, I am referring to the [mapclassify.NaturalBreaks](https://pysal.org/mapclassify/generated/mapclassify.NaturalBreaks.html#mapclassify-naturalbreaks) documentation.

So, let's say that my geodataframe is gdf and I follow along this [Automating GIS tutorial](https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/2019/notebooks/L4/reclassify.html).

```
import mapclassify
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('census.geojson', crs='epsg:3857')

classifier = mapclassify.NaturalBreaks(k=5, reverse=True)

gdf['median_household_index'] = gdf[['median_household_income']].apply(classifier)
```

would this work? I cannot find any parameters or documentation that discusses reverse reclassification. Appreciate any helpful links or code snippets.

thanks,

Chris

```
import pysal as ps
import mapclassify as mc
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('census.geojson', crs='epsg:3857')

classifier = mc.NaturalBreaks(k=5, reverse=True)

gdf['median_household_index'] = gdf[['median_household_income']].apply(classifier)

gdf.head()
```

in theory, I assume this would work...stackoverflow is asking me to post this minimum reproducible code example. but this does not work when I run it ...